# How do you type-in or copy paste \0 or VB null string character accidentally?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, spring-data

I have a client issue where sometimes this \0 ascii character is being entered where a Card Number (varchar 23 null) can be entered or left blank. This is in VB.NET and we are using DevExpress (8.3.3) WinForm Components. I tried few hours trying to replicate this. The client says she does not copy paste anything. So how do you accidentally type that in? It is causing issues as we either want empty String or null or the 23 digit card number. Anything other than that is not good. While I can write code to convert this into null or empty string, it is not a good solution as this needs to be done everywhere.

An additional solution would be to create an extension method to clean up, but that would also require code changes in multiple places. But I am still open to listen to ideas on this option too.

Or could this be happening when saving data? We are using Sping Data (ADO.NET).

The problem is I can't replicate it.

Comment: are they using a device to scan the cards? if so, i'd begin with checking that input.

Comment: no. just typing from the keyboard.

Comment: it is basically a grid component where we type and press tab or click to move to another cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate it with Ctrl + 0. While pressing it, nothing shows up. But then when I try to save the data, I can see it as \0 (in debug mode).

Comment: Normally, if someone gives you the right answer, you tick their answer as correct rather than answering the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of, if you're using the keyboard, would be holding down the ALT key, pressing the 0 key on the numeric keypad and releasing the ALT key again.

http://www.wikihow.com/Type-Symbols-Using-the-ALT-Key

Comment: I will try that when I get in today.